# Can't install x2go server on ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: x2go

I tried to install x2go server on ubuntu 18.04 but get following messages

```
carlo@cartracker:~$ sudo apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Einige Pakete konnten nicht installiert werden. Das kann bedeuten, dass
Sie eine unmögliche Situation angefordert haben oder, wenn Sie die
Unstable-Distribution verwenden, dass einige erforderliche Pakete noch
nicht erstellt wurden oder Incoming noch nicht verlassen haben.
Die folgenden Informationen helfen Ihnen vielleicht, die Situation zu lösen:

Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 x2goserver : Hängt ab von: libswitch-perl ist aber nicht installierbar
          Hängt ab von: libx2go-server-perl (< 4.1.0.3-0~1708~ubuntu18.04.1.1~) soll aber nicht installiert werden
          Hängt ab von: libx2go-server-perl (>= 4.1.0.3-0~1708~ubuntu18.04.1) soll aber nicht installiert werden
          Hängt ab von: pwgen ist aber nicht installierbar
          Empfiehlt: sshfs ist aber nicht installierbar
          Empfiehlt: x11-apps soll aber nicht installiert werden
          Empfiehlt: x11-session-utils soll aber nicht installiert werden
          Empfiehlt: x11-utils soll aber nicht installiert werden
          Empfiehlt: x11-xfs-utils ist aber nicht installierbar
          Empfiehlt: x11-xserver-utils soll aber nicht installiert werden
          Empfiehlt: x2goserver-extensions (< 4.1.0.3-0~1708~ubuntu18.04.1.1~) soll aber nicht installiert werden
          Empfiehlt: x2goserver-extensions (>= 4.1.0.3-0~1708~ubuntu18.04.1) soll aber nicht installiert werden
          Empfiehlt: x2goserver-fmbindings (< 4.1.0.3-0~1708~ubuntu18.04.1.1~) soll aber nicht installiert werden
          Empfiehlt: x2goserver-fmbindings (>= 4.1.0.3-0~1708~ubuntu18.04.1) soll aber nicht installiert werden
          Empfiehlt: x2goserver-printing (< 4.1.0.3-0~1708~ubuntu18.04.1.1~) soll aber nicht installiert werden
          Empfiehlt: x2goserver-printing (>= 4.1.0.3-0~1708~ubuntu18.04.1) soll aber nicht installiert werden
          Empfiehlt: xfonts-base soll aber nicht installiert werden
          Empfiehlt: xinit soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete.
```

the messages are in german, but it means that there are dependencies which are not installable or should not be installed.

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved, something in the packaging on this system went wrong. I compared sources.list with sources.list from a similar server and they where completely different, which should not be, and I don't know why, So I copied the sources.list from the other server and ran

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade

this ran fine, and then I installed x2goserver without problems.
I don't know, if this is the correct way to solve such problem, but in the end it worked for me